# What is a simple (not many relators) presentation of the Monster group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation, simple-groups, sporadic-groups

I know that the Monster group is the largest sporadic finite simple group. Is there any simple presentation of the Monster group? $79$ relators or less is preferable.

Comment: There is a known presentation and while it isn't pretty it isn't as horrible as one might expect.  See, e.g., [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/142205/presentation-of-the-monster-group)

Comment: According to Wikipedia, "Robert A. Wilson has found explicitly (with the aid of a computer) two invertible 196,882 by 196,882 matrices (with elements in the field of order 2) which together generate the monster group by matrix multiplication"

Comment: I'm pretty sure what you're looking for has yet to be discovered

Comment: Could you explain why you are looking for a presentation with at most $79$ relators? Why $79$ in particular? What would you do with such a presentation if you had one?

Comment: It is because the best one known has 80.

Comment: Do you realize that the accepted answer does not address your question?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to work with elements of the monster group, don't use $196882×196882$ binary matrices – or *any* explicit presentation for that matter. The main problem is that said group has no small linear representations.

Martin Seysen's [mmgroup](https://github.com/Martin-Seysen/mmgroup) package efficiently represents monster group elements as words on $7$ generators with reduction rules good enough to multiply random group elements in about $50$ milliseconds. Use this instead.

Comment: What is the explicit presentation used?

Comment: @635318657 it doesn't use any explicit one.

Comment: The question was about a **presentation** and your answer is about a *representation*: These are totally different things!

Comment: It says words on 7 generators…

Comment: I'm the author of the mmgroup package. My intention was to make practical computations in Monster possible, not to minimize the number of generators or relations. For a presentation of the Monster with few generators and relations, see the appendix by S. Norton in

https://qmro.qmul.ac.uk/xmlui/bitstream/handle/123456789/8484/Farooq_A_PhD_final.pdf